# Table exceeds margin with xltabular

Tags: tables, xltabular

Any suggestion for a descriptive table that exceeds the margins?
Here is my code and output:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular}
 \usepackage{float}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{ l | X }
\caption{Description of Variables used in this Study} 
 \label{table: vardescription}\\
\hline \hline
\textbf{\normalsize } & \textbf{\normalsize List of countries}  \\
\hline 
 \endhead

   \textbf{Emerging Markets:} & Algeria,Angola,Argentina,Bahrain,Bangladesh,Bolivia,Hong Kong,Brazil,Israel,Bulgaria,NewZealand,Singapore,Sri Lanka,Chile,China,Colombia,CostaRica,Uruguay,Dominican Republic,Ecuador,ElSalvador,Equatorial,Guinea,Ethiopia,Eritrea,Fiji,Djibouti,
Gabon,Gambia,Ghana,Kiribati,Grenada,Guatemala,Guinea,Guyana,Haiti,Honduras,
Hungary,India,Indonesia,Iran,Iraq,Jamaica,Kazakhstan,Jordan,Kenya,Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan,Laos,Lebanon,Lesotho,Latvia,Liberia,Libya,Malawi,Malaysia,Maldives,Mali,Malta,Mauritania,Mauritius,Mexico,Mongolia,Moldova,Morocco,Mozambique,Oman,Namibia,Nepal,Aruba,Vanuatu,Nicaragua,Niger,Nigeria,Micronesia (Federated States of),Marshall Islands,Pakistan,Pama,Papua,New Guinea,Paraguay,Peru,Philippines,Poland,Guinea-Bissau,Qatar,Romania,Russia,Rwanda,Nevis St. Lucia St. Vincent,Gredines San Marino,Saudi Arabia,Senegal, Seychelles,Sierra Leone,Slovakia,Slovenia,Somalia,South Africa,Zimbabwe,Sudan,Surime,Eswatini, Syria,Vietnam,Thailand,Togo,Tonga,Trinidad \& Tobago,United Arab Emirates,Tunisia,Turkey,Turkmenistan, Uganda, Ukraine,North Macedonia,Egypt,Tanzania,BurkiFaso,Uruguay,Uzbekistan,Venezuela,Samoa,Yemen,Zambia \\ \hline 

\textbf{Developed countries:} & Australia, Austria, Belgium,Canada,Denmark,Finland,France,
Germany,Ireland,Italy,Brunei,Japan,Netherlands,New Zealand,
Norway Poland,Portugal,Spain,Sweden,Switzerland,United Kingdom,
Croatia,Cyprus,Czechia,United States,Estonia,Georgia,Greece,
Iceland,Austria,South Korea,Lithuania,Madagascar,Netherlands, Antilles
 \\ \hline
 \end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe if you add spaces after the commas, LaTeX will take them as separate words... ;-)

Comment: Replace each comma with comma + space

Comment: Off-topic: Why is New Zealand listed under both emerging and devolped countries? And what explains Madagascar being listed as a developed country and Sinapore an Emerging economy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would define narrower first column (that text in it will be split into two lines) and instead `xltabular` use `longtnlr` table defined in the `tabularray` package.

BTW, from your MWE is no evident, that long table is really needed. For this can be used `tabularx` or `tblr` tables.

Showed are two cases:

- text in the second table is adjusted:

[image]

for this case the table preamble is:

- text in the second column is ragged right.

[image]

In this case complete MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\hyphenation{Ki-ri-ba-ti  ka-zakh-stan  Mal-di-ves  Ukra-ine
            }

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Description of variables used in this study},
  label = {table: vardescription}
                    ]{hline{1,Z} = 0.8pt, hline{2-Y} = 0.5pt,
                      colspec = {@{} X[0.15, l, font=\bfseries] 
                                     X[0.85, cmd=\RaggedRight] @{}},
                      row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                      rowhead =1
                      }
%
    & List of countries             \\
%
Emerging Markets
    & Algeria, Angola, Argentina, Aruba, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bolivia, Hong Kong, Brazil, Israel, Bulgaria, Burkina Faso, Singapore, Sri Lanka, Chile, China, Colombia, Costa Rica, Uruguay, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, Egypt, El Salvador, Equatorial Guinea, Eswatini, Ethiopia, Eritrea, Fiji, Djibouti, Gabon, Gambia, Ghana, Grenada, Guatemala, Guinea, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, India, Indonesia, Iran, Iraq, Jamaica, Kazakhstan, Jordan, Kenya, Kiribati, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Lebanon, Lesotho, Latvia, Liberia, Libya, Malawi, Malaysia, Maldives, Mali, Malta, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Micronesia (Federated States of), Mongolia, Moldova, Morocco, Mozambique, Marshall Islands, Namibia, Nepal, Nevis, New Zealand, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, North Macedonia, Oman Pakistan, Panama, Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Guinea-Bissau, Qatar, Romania, Russia, Rwanda, St. Lucia, St. Vincent \& Grenadines, San Marino, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Seychelles, Sierra Leone, Slovakia, Slovenia, Somalia, South Africa, Samoa, Sudan, Suriname, Syria, Vietnam, Thailand, Togo, Tonga, Trinidad \& Tobago, United Arab Emirates, Tunisia, Turkey, Turkmenistan, Uganda, Ukraine, Tanzania, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, Vanuatu, Venezuela, Yemen, Zambia, Zimbabwe \\
%
Developed countries
    & Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Ireland, Italy, Brunei, Japan, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, United States, Estonia, Georgia, Greece, Iceland, Austria, South Korea, Lithuania, Madagascar, Netherlands Antilles \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I would add "ka-zakh-stan" to the hyphenation exception list... :-)

Comment: @Mico, thank you very much for tip. Done!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to making sure that the commas are followed by spaces, fixing a few typos (such as missing "na " substrings in "BurkiFaso" "Pama", and Surime" [!], and adding missing commas and deleting spurious commas (as in "Equatorial,Guinea", do also consider *not* applying full justification to the material in the second column.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,xltabular,ragged2e,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} l >{\RaggedRight}X @{}}

\caption{Description of variables used in this study} \label{table: vardescription}\\
\toprule
& List of countries \\
\midrule
\endhead

\bottomrule
\endlastfoot

Emerging Markets
& Algeria, Angola, Argentina, Bahrain, Bangladesh, Bolivia, Hong Kong, Brazil, Israel, Bulgaria, New Zealand, Singapore, Sri Lanka, Chile, China, Colombia, Costa Rica, Uruguay, Dominican Republic, Ecuador, El Salvador, Equatorial Guinea, Ethiopia, Eritrea, Fiji, Djibouti, Gabon, Gambia, Ghana, Kiribati, Grenada, Guatemala, Guinea, Guyana, Haiti, Honduras, Hungary, India, Indonesia, Iran, Iraq, Jamaica, Kazakhstan, Jordan, Kenya, Kuwait, Kyrgyzstan, Laos, Lebanon, Lesotho, Latvia, Liberia, Libya, Malawi, Malaysia, Maldives, Mali, Malta, Mauritania, Mauritius, Mexico, Mongolia, Moldova, Morocco, Mozambique, Oman, Namibia, Nepal, Aruba, Vanuatu, Nicaragua, Niger, Nigeria, Micronesia (Federated States of), Marshall Islands, Pakistan, Panama, Papua New Guinea, Paraguay, Peru, Philippines, Poland, Guinea-Bissau, Qatar, Romania, Russia, Rwanda, Nevis, St.\ Lucia, St.\ Vincent \& Grenadines, San Marino, Saudi Arabia, Senegal, Seychelles, Sierra Leone, Slovakia, Slovenia, Somalia, South Africa, Zimbabwe, Sudan, Suriname, Eswatini, Syria, Vietnam, Thailand, Togo, Tonga, Trinidad \& Tobago, United Arab Emirates, Tunisia, Turkey, Turkmenistan, Uganda, Ukraine, North Macedonia, Egypt, Tanzania, Burkina Faso, Uruguay, Uzbekistan, Venezuela, Samoa, Yemen, Zambia \\
\midrule
Developed countries
& Australia, Austria, Belgium, Canada, Denmark, Finland, France, Germany, Ireland, Italy, Brunei, Japan, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, United Kingdom, Croatia, Cyprus, Czechia, United States, Estonia, Georgia, Greece, Iceland, Austria, South Korea, Lithuania, Madagascar, Netherlands Antilles \\

\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```